# Как опустить notify.js уведомление ниже?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

[image: Уведомление]

Код создания с помощью скрипта

```
$.notify(data.message, { 
   globalPosition: "top center", 
   className: "success"
})
```

CSS не помогает((

HTML разметка генерируется автоматически

```
<div class="notifyjs-corner" style="top: 0px; left: 45%;">
     <div class="notifyjs-wrapper notifyjs-hidable">
         <div class="notifyjs-arrow" style=""></div>
             <div class="notifyjs-container" style=""><div class="notifyjs-bootstrap-base notifyjs-bootstrap-success">
                 <span data-notify-text="">Данные о студенте успешно обновлены</span>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: globalPosition - вот сюда что можно передать?

Comment: GlobalPosition позволяет задавать положение уведомлений либо по краям либо по углам окна. 1 вариант сделать на странице невидимый элемент в нужном положении и привязать уведомления к нему. 2 Вариант поменять или добавить своё местоположение Globalposition в код notify.js. Напишу пример когда разберусь.

Comment: https://notifyjs.com/

Comment: {
  //required html representing each notification 
  html: "",
  //optional object to be converted to css
  classes: {
    <className>: {
      <propertyName>: <value> 
    },
    <className>: {
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
  //optional css to be inserted onto the page
  css: ""
}

Comment: Там можно поменять стиль уведомлений, но позиция там жестко задана. Тут просто нет такой опции точной настройки позиции.

Comment: @coder675 спасибо, еще один вопрос
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792231/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-notify-js-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более-менее приемлемый вариант - переопределить стиль. Если привязать уведомления к элементу, то тогда больше одного за раз не выводится.

```js
function test() {
$.notify("I'm over here !",{globalPosition: 'top center'});
}
```

```css
.notifyjs-corner {
    top: 70px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/notify/0.4.2/notify.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Проверить" onclick="test()">
```

Comment: работает без первого скрипта