# Уведомление notify.js не отображается(

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Код C#

```
   try
   {
   //бла бла
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
       ViewBag.Error = "Возникли проблемы при отправке вопроса!";
   }
```

Кнопка HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="Notification"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Отправить</button>
```

Скрипт создания уведомления

```
<script>
    function Notification() {
        if (@ViewBag.Error != null)
        {
            $.notify("Вопрос успешно отправлен",{ 
                globalPosition: "top center", // Распологается поцентру
                className: "success" // Успешное выполнение
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $.notify("Возникли проблемы при отправке вопроса!",{ 
                globalPosition: "top center", // Распологается поцентру
                className: "error" // Успешное выполнение
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `onclick="Notification"` => `onclick="Notification()"`

Comment: нет, не в этом ошибка @Rostyslav_Kuzmovych

Comment: попробуйте убрать `type="submit"` и посмотрите что получится

Comment: нет, не работает @Rostyslav_Kuzmovych

Comment: Тут что то похожее было https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935828/viewbag-check-to-see-if-item-exists-and-write-out-html-and-value-error Может нужно писать @if (ViewBag.Error != null)

Answer (score 0):

Работает :

```js
function Notification() {
  $.notify("Вопрос успешно отправлен", {
    globalPosition: "top center", // Распологается поцентру
    className: "success" // Успешное выполнение
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/notify/0.4.2/notify.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="Notification()"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Отправить</button>
```

Не работает :

```js
function Notification() {
  $.notify("Вопрос успешно отправлен", {
    globalPosition: "top center", // Распологается поцентру
    className: "success" // Успешное выполнение
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/notify/0.4.2/notify.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="Notification"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Отправить</button>
```

Comment: Скобки я уже поставил, но с if все рано не работает

Comment: посмотрите какой скрипт у вас генерируется и посмотрите есть ли ошибки в коносоле ?

Comment: Contact:102 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
dl.metabar.ru/static/storage/js/storage.min.js?version=201802221518:1 

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'domains' exceeded the quota.
    at HTMLScriptElement.a.onload (https://dl.metabar.ru/static/storage/js/storage.min.js?version=201802221518:1:6177)

Comment: судя по всему ошибка то не в нотифай, она гдето тут : dl.metabar.ru/static/storage/js/storage.min.js

Comment: не правильный синтаксис в строке
@ViewBag.Error

Comment: По моему нужно писать @if (ViewBag.Error != null)